# Facing problem of "Question Banned" from a very long time

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I had been "Question Banned" from a long time but this problem is resolved before 2 days. From today i am facing the same problem.I am unable to ask any question from Stack overflow.

Please provide me solution. I have tried to support positively to the site. I have also read all the documents for "Question Banned" and applied on me.